# custom crafting skript minecraft

Tags: minecraft

So the problem is: on minecraft with skript I want to find a way to create custom recipes without addons !

I try with that code but it's not working !

```
on load:
    set {hamer-data} to netherite pickaxe named "&7Hammer" with lore "&7The hammer is in devloppement"
    register new shaped recipe for {hamer-data} using air, netherite ingot, netherite ingot, air, stick, air, air, stick, air
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your variable, try this:

**Without Variables**

```
on load:
    register new shaped recipe for netherite pickaxe named "&7Hammer" using air, netherite ingot, netherite ingot, air, stick, air, air, stick, air
```

**With Variables**

````
on load:
    set {hammer} to netherite pickaxe named "&7Hammer"
    register new shaped recipe for {hammer} using air, netherite ingot, netherite ingot, air, stick, air, air, stick, air```
````

Comment: This isn't late at all :)

Answer (score 0):

at the end you need to add the ID of the item. if you look at the tutorial on skhub.com you can see that they add an item ID

on load:
set {_hellingot} to brick named "&cHell Ingot"
register new shaped recipe for {_hellingot} named "&cHell Ingot" using iron ingot, gold ingot, iron ingot, gold ingot, netherite ingot, gold ingot, iron ingot, gold ingot and iron ingot with id "hell_ingot"

Answer (score 0):

In Skript, as of now (13/05/2023) there is no way to add custom recipes without the use of an external addon. (Although the SkriptLang Team is working on it)
That said, here is THE addon you should be looking for when wanting to add custom recipes or just handling recipes in general: SkBee

[Source](https://skripthub.net/docs/?id=4051)

```vb
register [new] (shaped|shapeless) recipe for %itemtype% (using|with ingredients) %itemtypes/materialchoices% with id %string% [in group %string%]
```

This effect can either register a shaped or shapeless recipe for a set item and with set ingredients, an id is in fact required while a group is not.

Other useful recipe utilities within SkBee:

[Source](https://skripthub.net/docs/?id=4047)

```vb
register [new] (furnace|(blast furnace|blasting)|smok(er|ing)|campfire) recipe for %itemtype% (using|with ingredient) %itemtype/materialchoice% with id %string% [[and ]with exp[erience] %number%] [[and ]with cook[ ]time %timespan%] [in group %string%]
```

[Source](https://skripthub.net/docs/?id=5620)

```vb
[(all [[of] the]|the)] [((mc|minecraft)|custom)] recipe[s] [(for|of) %itemtypes%]
```

[Source](https://skripthub.net/docs/?id=4050)

```vb
remove [(custom|(mc|minecraft))] recipe[s] %strings%

remove all [((mc|minecraft))] recipe[s]
```